# How can I improve the launch time of my flutter firebase app?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mobile-application

My app is already live on the Play Store, but it takes almost 15-20 seconds to fully open and get to the home screen.
I am using Firebase for backend with my flutter app.
I have included step by step code that executes when my app starts.

### main.dart

```
AndroidNotificationChannel channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel',
  'High Importance Notifications',
  description: 'This channel is used for high importance notifications',
  importance: Importance.max,
  playSound: true,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Initialize Firebase App
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Activate Firebase App Check
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
  );

  // Initialize Google Mobile Ads
  await MobileAds.instance.initialize();

  // Set preferred device orientation
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  // Initialize Flutter Local Notifications Plugin
  // FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  // Set foreground notification presentation options
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => AppNavigationProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => SellerFormProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => LocationProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    registerMessaging();
  }

  void registerMessaging() async {
    await compute(_registerMessaging, null);
  }

  static Future<void> _registerMessaging(void _) async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      final RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      final AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              channelDescription: channel.description,
              playSound: true,
              importance: Importance.max,
              priority: Priority.high,
              color: greenColor,
              icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'App name',
      color: blueColor,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Rubik'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const LoadingScreen(),
      onUnknownRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => const ErrorScreen(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

### loading_screen.dart

```
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoadingScreen> createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //check whether user is logged in or not. Then navigate her accordingly.
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user != null) {
        Get.offAll(() => const MainScreen(selectedIndex: 0));
      } else {
        Get.offAll(() => const LandingScreen());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: whiteColor,
      body: Center(
        child: CustomLoadingIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### main_screen.dart

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;
  const MainScreen({super.key, required this.selectedIndex});

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final FirebaseServices _services = FirebaseServices();
  final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  late StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> subscription;
  bool isDeviceConnected = false;
  bool isAlertSet = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getConnectivity();
  }

  showNetworkError() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      backgroundColor: transparentColor,
      isDismissible: false,
      enableDrag: false,
      isScrollControlled: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              color: whiteColor,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 15,
              left: 15,
              right: 15,
              top: 15,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Network Connection Lost',
                    style: GoogleFonts.interTight(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/no-network.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  semanticLabel: 'no network connection',
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: greyColor,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Please check your internet connection',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    softWrap: true,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: GoogleFonts.interTight(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                CustomButtonWithoutIcon(
                  text: 'Re-Connect',
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Get.back();
                    setState(() {
                      isAlertSet = false;
                    });
                    isDeviceConnected =
                        await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
                    if (!isDeviceConnected) {
                      showNetworkError();
                      setState(() {
                        isAlertSet = true;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  borderColor: redColor,
                  bgColor: redColor,
                  textIconColor: whiteColor,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> getConnectivity() async {
    await for (final _ in Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged) {
      isDeviceConnected = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
      if (!isDeviceConnected && !isAlertSet) {
        showNetworkError();
        setState(() => isAlertSet = true);
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> onSellButtonClicked() async {
    final userData = await _services.getCurrentUserData();
    if (userData['location'] != null) {
      Get.to(
        () => const SellerCategoriesListScreen(),
      );
    } else {
      Get.to(() => const LocationScreen(isOpenedFromSellButton: true));
      showSnackBar(
        content: 'Please set your location to sell products',
        color: redColor,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer2<LocationProvider, AppNavigationProvider>(
      builder: (context, locationProv, mainProv, child) {
        final int selectedIndex = mainProv.currentPageIndex;

        final List<Widget> pages = [
          HomeScreen(
            locationData: locationProv.locationData,
          ),
          const MyChatsScreen(),
          const MyFavoritesScreen(),
          const MyProfileScreen(),
        ];

        const List<IconData> iconsList = [
          MdiIcons.homeOutline,
          MdiIcons.chatOutline,
          MdiIcons.heartOutline,
          MdiIcons.accountCircleOutline,
        ];

        const List<IconData> selectedIconsList = [
          MdiIcons.home,
          MdiIcons.chat,
          MdiIcons.heart,
          MdiIcons.accountCircle,
        ];

        const List<String> titlesList = [
          'Explore',
          'Chats',
          'Favorites',
          'Account',
        ];

        void onItemTapped(int index) {
          mainProv.switchToPage(index);
        }

        void onFloatingActionButtonPressed() {
          if (!user!.emailVerified &&
              user!.providerData[0].providerId == 'password') {
            Get.to(() => const EmailVerificationScreen());
          } else {
            onSellButtonClicked();
          }
        }

        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: whiteColor,
          body: IndexedStack(
            index: selectedIndex,
            children: pages,
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: blueColor,
            elevation: 0,
            tooltip: 'List a product',
            enableFeedback: true,
            onPressed: onFloatingActionButtonPressed,
            child: const Center(
              child: Icon(
                MdiIcons.plus,
                size: 35,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar.builder(
            onTap: onItemTapped,
            gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
            activeIndex: selectedIndex,
            backgroundColor: greyColor,
            elevation: 5,
            height: 55,
            leftCornerRadius: 10,
            rightCornerRadius: 10,
            notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.defaultEdge,
            splashColor: transparentColor,
            itemCount: pages.length,
            tabBuilder: (index, isActive) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    selectedIndex == index
                        ? selectedIconsList[index]
                        : iconsList[index],
                    size: 24,
                    color: blackColor,
                  ),
                  AutoSizeText(
                    titlesList[index],
                    maxLines: 1,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: selectedIndex == index
                          ? FontWeight.w600
                          : FontWeight.w500,
                      color: blackColor,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

### home_screen.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final LocationData? locationData;
  const HomeScreen({
    super.key,
    this.locationData,
  });

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabBarController;
  final _services = FirebaseServices();
  final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  String area = '';
  String city = '';
  String state = '';
  bool isLocationEmpty = false;
  bool isLoading = true;

  late DateTime currentBackPressTime;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabBarController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    );
    _getCurrentUserData();
  }

  void _getCurrentUserData() async {
    final value = await _services.getCurrentUserData();
    if (value['location'] == null) {
      _getEmptyLocationUI();
    } else {
      _getAddressToUI(value);
    }
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _getAddressToUI(DocumentSnapshot<Object?> value) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        area = value['location']['area'];
        city = value['location']['city'];
        state = value['location']['state'];
      });
    }
  }

  _getEmptyLocationUI() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        isLocationEmpty = true;
        tabBarController.index = 1;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabBarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: whiteColor,
      body: AppBody(),
      );
  }
}
```

**location_screen.dart**

```
class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isOpenedFromSellButton;
  const LocationScreen({Key? key, required this.isOpenedFromSellButton})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LocationScreen> createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  final FirebaseServices _services = FirebaseServices();
  final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final Location location = Location();
  late bool serviceEnabled;
  late PermissionStatus permissionGranted;
  bool isLoading = false;

  Future<bool> getAddress() async {
    final locationProv = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false);
    try {
      List placemarks = await geocode.placemarkFromCoordinates(
        locationProv.locationData!.latitude as double,
        locationProv.locationData!.longitude as double,
        localeIdentifier: 'en_IN',
      );
      await _services.updateUserDetails(user!.uid, {
        'location': {
          'latitude': locationProv.locationData!.latitude,
          'longitude': locationProv.locationData!.longitude,
          'street': placemarks[0].street.toString(),
          'area': placemarks[0].subLocality == ''
              ? placemarks[0].locality.toString()
              : placemarks[0].subLocality.toString(),
          'city': placemarks[0].locality.toString(),
          'state': placemarks[0].administrativeArea.toString(),
          'country': placemarks[0].country.toString(),
          'pin': placemarks[0].postalCode.toString(),
        },
      });
      if (mounted) {
        showSnackBar(
          content: placemarks[0].subLocality == ''
              ? 'Location set to ${placemarks[0].locality.toString()}'
              : 'Location set to ${placemarks[0].subLocality.toString()}',
          color: blueColor,
        );
      }
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(
        content: 'Unable to get your current location. Please try again',
        color: redColor,
      );
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> getUserLocation() async {
    final locationProv = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final Location location = Location();
    bool serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus permissionGranted;

    try {
      serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
        if (!serviceEnabled) {
          showSnackBar(
            content:
                'Location services are disabled. Please enable services to continue',
            color: redColor,
          );
          return false;
        }
      }
      permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
      if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
        permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
        if (permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
          showSnackBar(
            content:
                'Location access was denied. Please allow access for a better experience',
            color: redColor,
          );
          return false;
        }
      }
      if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.deniedForever) {
        showSnackBar(
          content:
              'Location services are permanently disabled, unable to fetch location',
          color: redColor,
        );
        return false;
      }
      final value = await location.getLocation();
      locationProv.updateLocation(value);
      return await getAddress();
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(
        content: 'Unable to get your current location. Please try again',
        color: redColor,
      );
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: whiteColor,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.2,
        backgroundColor: whiteColor,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: blackColor),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Set your location',
          style: GoogleFonts.interTight(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            color: blackColor,
            fontSize: 15,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: Text(
                'By setting your location, you can receive tailored product suggestions in your area and market your own products for sale',
                style: GoogleFonts.interTight(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
              child: Text(
                'In order to access all of our offerings, we must know where to look for them',
                style: GoogleFonts.interTight(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: lightBlackColor,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              height: size.height * 0.2,
              width: size.height * 0.2,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                color: whiteColor,
                border: greyBorder,
              ),
              child: const SVGPictureWidget(
                url:
                    'example',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                semanticsLabel: 'Location image',
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            isLoading
                ? Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 15,
                      right: 15,
                    ),
                    child: const LoadingButton(
                      bgColor: blueColor,
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 15,
                      right: 15,
                    ),
                    child: CustomButton(
                      text: 'Use Current Location',
                      icon: Ionicons.locate,
                      bgColor: blueColor,
                      borderColor: blueColor,
                      textIconColor: whiteColor,
                      onPressed: () async {
                        try {
                          setState(() {
                            isLoading = true;
                          });
                          bool value = await getUserLocation();
                          if (!value) return;
                          if (!widget.isOpenedFromSellButton) {
                            Get.offAll(
                                () => const MainScreen(selectedIndex: 0));
                          } else {
                            Get.back();
                            Get.to(() => const SellerCategoriesListScreen());
                          }
                          setState(() {
                            isLoading = false;
                          });
                        } catch (e) {
                          showSnackBar(
                            content: 'Something went wrong. Please try again',
                            color: redColor,
                          );
                        } finally {
                          setState(() {
                            isLoading = false;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 15,
                right: 15,
                bottom: 15,
              ),
              child: CustomButtonWithoutIcon(
                text: 'Skip',
                bgColor: whiteColor,
                borderColor: blackColor,
                textIconColor: blackColor,
                isDisabled: isLoading,
                onPressed: () => Get.back(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried everything to my knowledge, but still the launch time isn't getting shortened.
Reducing the time by just 5-10% would make a huge difference in user retention rate of my app.

Please help.

Comment: Just cutting down 5-6 seconds on the launch time would be a huge help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to find which steps are slowing down the launch of your app. I use Firebase Cloud Messaging too but my app launches within 3 or 4 seconds.

Comment: @Crizant I am unable to find out what step is slowing down the app. can you help?

Comment: Consider using [**Future.wait**](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html) method to wrap those multiple await calls into one, so they can run parallelly. As from the first look of it they don't seem to be dependent on each other. It is Analogical of `Promise.all()` from JavaScript but in Dart.

Comment: @RohitKharche Can you explain in detail how to do it?

Comment: @VasudevSoni Yes, You just need to wrap all the async await calls for initialization into Future.await which will initialize all those services parallarly which will reduce the start time.

Comment: Add a `print` statement before each `await` statements, then you can observe which step takes the longest time.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 steps you should consider in order to reduce loading time.

1. Find out which calls are necessery to be there on your initial loading (meaning what the user sees on the first screen), and move the rest in a lateInit function.
2. Use async functions when possible, in order not to delay the process.
3. Fist time loading may be longer, but after that you can "cache" specific things and speed up the loading time for next time.

In your case, you might had a "light" Homescreen, that loads first with only the information needed. Binance app is a good example, which loads the homepage and later you get the values of your account or other ratios.

Comment: My home screen opens up quickly, but after that the data loads up from firebase in a list view, tab view and grid view. This data loading takes up most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

> My home screen opens up quickly, but after that the data loads up from firebase in a list view, tab view and grid view. This data loading takes up most of the time.

1. Are you loading all the data from the DB ? If yes, you will have to use Skip / Limit
2. The initializing Google AdMob should be `unawaited` since the app loading up should not depend on whether the ads get loaded or not.

Comment: How do I make the admob function unawaited? Please tell me the code

Comment: I am loading all the data from firestore database, and I am already using limit functions.

Comment: Please refer this link to execute Future unawaited : 

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/unawaited.html#:~:text=You%20should%20use%20unawaited%20to,or%20otherwise%20handled)%20elsewhere%20too.

1. Try setting up indexes in firestore, that might help speed up the things.
2. Make parallel API calls using `Future.wait` https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.1/dart-async/Future/wait.html

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you posted FirebaseServices file too. Since you've mentioned that you're using limit for your Firebase query, My guess is that you're awaiting the user's current location from the Location Provider. Getting a user's location can take time depending on the network. Im sure we can improve it by adding the get user location call a bit ahead in the background async.

Comment: I have added the location_screen.dart which includes the function used to get user location.

Answer (score 0):

I would measure and log the durations of all futures from the moment of creating (starting) them and when they finish. Maybe it's one rogue method that needs some work. This can be done creating a DateTime object before and after a method call and using DateTime.difference to get a Duration that can be logged.

Also it is possible to combine several futures into one await. This is my main().

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Async init futures (these start immediately)
  Future<bool> getStorageInitializedFuture = GetStorage.init();
  Future<void> localNotificationsFuture = NotificationController.initializeLocalNotifications();
  Future<User> userFuture = LocalStorageProvider().loadUserFromDisk();
  Future<AudioPlayerHandler> audioPlayerFuture = AudioService.init(
    builder: () => AudioPlayerHandler(),
    config: AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.ryanheise.myapp.channel.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
    ),
  );
  Future sharedPrefrencesFuture = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  // Await all futures, will return when the future that takes the longest finishes,
  // group the futures with the longest execution time in this list so the completion 
  // times of these are not all added to the total wait time, 
  // but just the wait time for the longest future. 
  List<dynamic> results = await Future.wait(
      [
        getStorageInitializedFuture,
        localNotificationsFuture,
        userFuture,
        audioPlayerFuture,
        sharedPrefrencesFuture,
      ]
  );
  User user = results[2];
  AudioPlayerHandler audioPlayerHandler = results[3];
  bool notificationsAllowed = await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed();
  if(!notificationsAllowed) {
    AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications().then((value) {
      if(value) {
        NotificationScheduler(user).scheduleAll();
      }
    });
  }
  else{
    NotificationScheduler(user).scheduleAll();
  }
  runApp(MyApp(user));
}
```

Also your code might benefit from using .then on the futures to chain the subsequent firebase calls instead of awaiting all.

A last idea (but I did not test this) is to not await any future that is not strictly needed to build MyApp but instead pass these futures to the constructor of MyApp and use the FutureBuilder widget for the parts of your UI that depend on the future information. With FutureBuilder the children are build on completion of the future.
So only the widgets that are dependend on the future data are delayed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using firebase cloud functions? If yes, are you waiting for some network call to finish before loading the app?
If your answer is yes to both of these then cold start of firebase functions is the problem. To resolve the issue, you can set minimum instances of firebase function to 1